# How do I get the maximum and minimum dates in a group of repeating cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to get the maximum and minimum date and time from a group of cells which have similar names. My table structure would be as follows:

```
+------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  ID  |  Stage   |       Date       |       Min        |       Max        |
+------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 2895 | Planning | 01-06-2016 15:40 | 01-06-2016 15:40 | 06-06-2016 13:06 |
| 2895 | Costing  | 02-06-2016 17:59 | 02-06-2016 17:59 | 27-06-2016 14:13 |
| 2895 | Costing  | 04-06-2016 10:16 | 02-06-2016 17:59 | 27-06-2016 14:13 |
| 2895 | Planning | 06-06-2016 13:06 | 01-06-2016 15:40 | 06-06-2016 13:06 |
| 2895 | Costing  | 08-06-2016 11:25 | 02-06-2016 17:59 | 27-06-2016 14:13 |
| 2895 | Booking  | 09-06-2016 13:16 | 09-06-2016 13:16 | 27-06-2016 19:33 |
| 2895 | New      | 17-06-2016 23:47 | 17-06-2016 23:47 | 17-06-2016 23:47 |
| 2895 | Costing  | 27-06-2016 14:13 | 02-06-2016 17:59 | 27-06-2016 14:13 |
| 2895 | Booking  | 27-06-2016 19:33 | 09-06-2016 13:16 | 27-06-2016 19:33 |
| 3113 | Costing  | 07-06-2016 17:33 | 07-06-2016 17:33 | 11-06-2016 11:48 |
| 3113 | Costing  | 11-06-2016 11:48 | 07-06-2016 17:33 | 11-06-2016 11:48 |
| 3113 | Booking  | 11-06-2016 19:12 | 11-06-2016 19:12 | 15-09-2016 18:11 |
| 3113 | Won      | 22-07-2016 17:29 | 22-07-2016 17:29 | 15-09-2016 18:12 |
| 3113 | Booking  | 23-08-2016 14:07 | 11-06-2016 19:12 | 15-09-2016 18:11 |
| 3113 | Won      | 23-08-2016 14:13 | 22-07-2016 17:29 | 15-09-2016 18:12 |
| 3113 | Booking  | 15-09-2016 18:11 | 11-06-2016 19:12 | 15-09-2016 18:11 |
| 3113 | Won      | 15-09-2016 18:12 | 22-07-2016 17:29 | 15-09-2016 18:12 |
+------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

There could be multiple stages under a ID and different dates. I would like to know the Minimum date and the Maximum date.

I have been able to achieve this on Google Sheets by using a query

`=query($A2:$C18,"select C where A='" & A2 &"' and B='" & B2 &"' order by C desc limit 1 ")`

I get an error while trying this. How would I achieve this on Excel? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/minimum-if-multiple-criteria

Comment: @TimWilliams - Thanks but, can't figure this out. Even after Ctrl + Shift + Entering, the formular won't work. Have also done a **Ctrl + accent mark ** to toggle formula on/off. Still won't work. And, how will this show the minimum and maximum dates on each row against common Stages? Would appreciate it a lot if you can show me how this is done.

Comment: Is it possible your dates are not actually dates but just text?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `MINIFS` in excel.

In `D2` enter `=MINIFS($C$2:$C$18,$A$2:$A$18,A2,$B$2:$B$18,B2)` and drag down.
Similarly. use `MAXIFS` in `E2` (assuming your data range is `A1` to `E18`

This formula is similar to `SUMIFS`. It returns minimum value from 1st range based on criteria specified.

Note: calculation will be very slow on high volume of data with this formula

Answer (score 0):

This array formula might work for you:

```
=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$18=A2,IF($B$2:$B$18=B2,$C$2:$C$18)))
```

or

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$18=A2,IF($B$2:$B$18=B2,$C$2:$C$18)))
```

Because these are array formulas you must apply them with **Ctrl**+**Shift**+**Enter**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula like:

```
{=MAX(IF(($B$4:$B$20=B2)*($A$4:$A$20=A2),$C$4:$C$20,""))}
```